# how to use href property in php using anchor tag

Tags: php

I have written

```
echo '<a href="javascript:q=(document.location.href);void(open('http://example.com/submit.php?url='+escape(q),'_self','resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status'));">'.'click here'.'</a>'
```

in php file it gives

**unexpected:   identifier 'http'**

error. Please give me solution.

Comment: Replace `'` with `\'` _in your PHP string_.

Comment: Syntax highlighting shows you exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo'<a href="javascript:q=(document.location.href);void(open(\'http://example.com/submit.php?url=\'+escape(q),\'_self\',\'resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status\'));">click here</a>'
```

you need to escape quotes inside your echo try this